# Referencing dynamically created datagridview objects on external button click

Tags: c#, button, datagridview

So I have a C# application that imports an Excel workbook. For each sheet in the book, I am dynamically creating a new tab in my base tab control. Each tab has a split container. The top container has a button, the bottom has a datagridview that gets populated with that sheet's data. The names of each of these controls is set with the worksheet name, preceded with a variance of the control type (i.e. If sheet name is "User List", the button is named "btnUserList"; the DataGridView is named "dgvUserList", etc, etc). This is all working great!

The purpose of the external button is to allow the user to export the range of cells they have selected in the grid to a pipe-delimited text file. My issue is that I can't "bind" the buttons to their related DataGridView objects.

When I click the button, I need some way to reference the associated DataGridView so I can pass it to my function that gets the selected cell range data. I tried to set the Button.Tag attribute to the name of the DataGridView, but as that is just a string, I can't actually use it to reference the actual DataGridView.

I have been searching for a solution to this for hours...so many references are related to the embedded DataGridViewButtonColumn, but that approach will not work for me, so I am really hoping someone can help me out here. Thanks!!

So here is a an example button, note the Tag is named to the same name used when the DataGridView object is dynamically created for the same sheet:

```
    private Button RunTimeCreatedButton;

    RunTimeCreatedButton.Name = "btnUserList";
    RunTimeCreatedButton.Tag = "dgvUserList"
    RunTimeCreatedButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.dynButton_Click);
    this.Controls.Add(RunTimeCreatedButton);
```

This is my onclick event:

```
    private void dynButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var button = (Button)sender;
        string theTag = button.Tag.ToString();

        // How do I get "theTag" to reference the actual DataGridView it is named after??

        // Send the DataGridView reference to the export method:
        exportRange(theTag);

    }

    private void exportRange(DataGridView dgv)
    {

        // This is where I need to start referencing the DataGridView
        Int32 selectedCellCount = dgv.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
        ....do rest of stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your DataGridView control by it's name like this:

```
this.Controls[dgvName]
```

edit:

Your control hierarchy is really complicated so here is your  summary:

- Your Form contains TabControl
- TabControl contains TabPages
- TabPages contains SplitContainer
- SplitContainer contains two panel
- Panel contains your dataGridView

  private void exportRange(string dgvName)
      {

  ```
      var tabPage = tabControlName.TabPages[tabName];
      var splitContainer = (SplitContainer)tabPage.Controls[ContainerName];
      var dgv = splitContainer.Panel1.Controls[dgvName];

  }
  ```

Comment: I am getting the following error message by using that. Any suggestions on enhancing it? 

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: That resolved my error, but my dgv is coming back null. It looks like the Controls list is only picking up the SplitContainer that the  button resides in. I'm thinking I need to re-arrange a few things in how my tabs are built...or is "this." causing some issues? Sorry for all the newb questions...learning all this as I go!

Comment: oh sorry i miss again :) you are using tabControl right? in my code "this" refers your entire Form,but your TabControl contains your DataGridViews, not your form. So you must use tabControl.Controls collection, i update my code for last time i hope it helps

Comment: That is returning a null as well, but I see where you are going with this. Since my tabContainer also contains a SplitContainer (which is what contains the dgv), I am guessing I need to drill through all these different objects. I'll keep playing with it. Thanks so much!

Comment: You are welcome,i try it and the last (i promise its last :) problem is your DataGridView control belongs a tabPage,which means correct way to acces datagridview is: tabControlName.TabPages[tabName].Controls[dgvName] (and don't forget accept my message as answer if it solve your problem :))

Comment: OK...getting closer but still getting null!! I should explain that within each tab, is another splitContainer with 2 panels. The bottom panel is where the dgv resides, so I presume one more level needs to be added in to the mix here. Problem I am now having is that the container is dynamically named as well. I am going to keep experimenting!

Comment: yeah you will never access this datagridview :)) your controls hierarchy is really complicated, you must receive tabPage and then access splitContainer in it,and then acces Panel control which contains dataGridview and finally access dataGridView ...

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit convoluted, but I think I will look into re-organizing it to avoid all the stacked controls. I really appreciate your help with this Selman22!!

Comment: check last code,if you apply it appropriately,it should work..in addition splitContainer's panel, i don't know which panel contains your datagridview you might want to change it

Comment: you are welcome,sorry about all those edits, i didn't read your question carefully :)